# Binding textbox.text from window to label.content in main window

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Edit: Re-did this question, felt like I was asking too much and wasn't being clear before.

I have a window called `Range.xaml` which is displayed when a user clicks a button on the `MainWindow.xaml`. There is are three `textboxes` on `Range.xaml` that, when the window opens, I want the `text` of those to display the `content` in the `label` on `MainWindow.xaml` (I'm going to be formatting the `text` in those `textboxes` later). Note: The `text` WILL be a `DateTime`.

I'm having a hard time getting it to work properly.

In my `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Label Name="TestLabel"
```

In my `Range.xaml`:

```
<TextBox Name="SDate1" />
<TextBox Name="SDate2" />
<TextBox Name="STime" />
```

So `TestLabel.Content` will change at some point before the `Range` window pops up. Let's just say for now:

`TestLabel.Content = "03/21/90";`

Then to open the `Range` window:

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Range range = new Range();
    range.ShowDialog();
}
```

How do I bind the three `textboxes`' `text` to display `03/21/90` (the `label`'s `content`)??

I've tried setting up a public `get/set` function for the `label`'s content and binding the `text` of the `textboxes` to that, but they appeared empty.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Text you are Binding is a `String` type. You should bind it to a string.

```
public String DateInViewModel
{
    get { return _dateInViewModel.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"); }
    set
    {
        //You can use TryParseExact to avoid format error exception
        _dateInViewModel = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DateInViewModel"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. Did not see this answer. Tried being more clear with my question.